# when an android app show invalid domain or package name android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Recently I've encountered an issue and that is

invalid domain or package name android

Can anyone please describe to me why this type of issue occurred?

Comment: `I've encountered`, where ? when ? post your code.

Comment: please ask question in detailed format for better understading. Kindly share the Error message. if possible, the code line where the error is indicating, etc.